# Control Enabled/Disabled behaviour in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, controls

I have an application that has a lot of textboxes in it. Also this textboxes actually are never disabled, but rather become ReadOnly instead. I prefer using one property of ContentControl for all my controls, but if i set IsEnabled to false all my textboxes become disabled. How can i make them go to readonly mode? I prefer not making my own control though, maybe i can use styles or something to reassign behaviour?

**Edit:** I actually am looking for solution that allows me to use binding to bind state of all controls(IsReadOnly) through binding in one place. Like:

```
<ContentControl IsEnabled="{Binding boolFlag, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        ....
        <TextBox/>
    </Grid>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Could you add some code of how are you using single property ?

Comment: Do I understand right, that all your `TextBox` controls are children of `ContentControl`?

Comment: ContentControl can contain only one child. They're probably inside a grid or something..

Comment: well yes, they are inside a grid. Bur grid doesn't have IsEnabled property, so i have to put grid inside of ContentControl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the use of the DataForm control would be best in your case. It would allow you to control every field within it as a group. It does provide the IsReadOnly option plus it comes with many free features that are very nice.

This video gives a good introduction

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/data-controls/dataform-control

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Creating-Rich-Data-Forms-in-Silverlight-3-Introduction.aspx

http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html
Look for dataform

Cheers,

Comment: yeah, looks like what i need, i'll look into it tomorrow

Comment: Well yeah it turned out to be what is the best for my situation, so let's mark it an answer. Unfortunately we don't have time to convert our project to datafoms right now, so i'll code my own content control instead(

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a  simple extension method for your ContentControl that will make textBoxes `IsReadOnly = True`. For example:

```
public static class ContentControlEx
{
    public static void DisableTextBoxes(this ContentControl contentControl)
    {
        FrameworkElement p = contentControl as FrameworkElement;
        var ts = p.GetChildren<TextBox>();
        ts.ForEach(a => { if (!a.IsReadOnly) a.IsReadOnly = true; });
    }

    public static List<T> GetChildren<T>(this UIElement parent) where T : UIElement
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            UIElement child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i) as UIElement;
            if (child != null) {
                if (child is T)
                    list.Add(child as T);

                List<T> l1 = GetChildren<T>(child);
                foreach (T u in l1)
                    list.Add(u);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

usage (for ContentControl with Name = "content"):

```
content.DisableTextBoxes();
```

I have a XAML like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <ContentControl IsEnabled="True" Name="content">
        <StackPanel Margin="15">
            <TextBox Width="150" Name="tb1" Margin="5" Text="{Binding tb1}" />
            <TextBox Width="150" Name="tb2" Margin="5" Text="{Binding tb2}" />
            <TextBox Width="150" Name="tb3" Margin="5" Text="{Binding tb3}"/>
            <TextBox Width="150" Name="tb4" Margin="5" Text="{Binding tb4}"/>
            <Button Name="bSubmit" Click="bSubmit_Click">Make Textboxes readonly</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

Let me know if it helps...

Comment: I updated my question to describe more precisely what i need. Hmmm... I'm not sure i would be able to make extention dependency property(((

Comment: But if i decide to make my own version of ContentControl your post would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you want to bind each `TextBox.IsReadOnlyProperty` to a single bool.

You might try something like this, in a similar fashion to how you bound the `IsEnabled` property of the `ContentControl`:

```
<TextBox IsReadOnly="{Binding boolFlag, Mode=OneWay}" ... /> <!-- in each of your textboxes -->
```

This should provide you what you need: change `boolFlag`, every textbox turns on or off.

Comment: I don't want to copy-paste binding to every control i have on a form!